# Replacing Child fragments

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm a newbie to Android development. Im using Xamarin Android to develop an Android Application. im having problems when replacing fragments within the fragments, working on a Template app where i want to replace the FragmentA with FragmentB. Within the Main Activity, the content_frame is being replaced by FragmentA.

here is the Code i currently have

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="MAIN ACTIVITY" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/parent_fragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Label = "NestedFrags", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Fragment fragA = new FragmentA();
            FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.parent_fragment, fragA).Commit();
        }
    }
```

FragmentA.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Parent Fragment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentA.cs

```
public class FragmentA : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            transaction.Add(Resource.Id.child_fragment, fragmentB).Commit();
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fraga, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

FragmentB.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Child Fragment of A"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentB.cs

```
 public class FragmentB : Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragb, container, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Until now, im able to replace the Fragments one on top of another. but im trying to replace the fragmentA completely with fragmentB. Can anyone please help me? I dont mind if anyone can answer in Java as i just need something to work with, i will make changes to my code according to Java solution.

Thanks in Advance for all or any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace Fragment A with Fragment B you have to do pretty much the same you are already doing when adding the Fragment A:

```
        Fragment fragB = new FragmentB();
        FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.parent_fragment, fragB).Commit();
```

Just make sure you are placing the fragment on the main container (the one in your main layout).

Comment: Hi @CarlosJimenez   I tried that, but the app abruptly closes when i change the           transaction.Add(Resource.Id.child_fragment, fragmentB).Commit(); with     transaction.Add(Resource.Id.parent_fragment, fragmentB).Commit();

Comment: try with transaction.Replace

Comment: sorry i tried with that as well but same result, the app breaks. i also tried ChildFragmentManager. same result as before

Comment: Can you post the log with the error? Also, where in your code are you doing the transaction?

Comment: I noticed you are using `ChildFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();` on the FragmentB transaction, that might be the cause of your problem, you need to use `FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();`

Comment: Thanks CarlosJimenez you're right. ChildFragmentManager is causing the issue. once i took it off, its working as expected.